# How to completely ignore permission errors in Discord.JS?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

How can I ignore all bot's permission errors in **Discord.JS**? I have already the checking bot's permissions functions, but this function doesn't work on the channels permissions. You can answer how can I ignore all bot's permission errors (if it can) or how to check permissions even in the channels permissions.
There is my error (it's the same as not checking permissions):

```
throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
        ^

DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check [GuildMember#permissions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=permissions) to see if the client has a certain permission in a guild.

```js
// Example

const botMember = message.guild.me;
if (!botMember.permissions.has('KICK_MEMBERS')) {
   // Code
} else {
   // Error Handling 
}
```

Additionally, you can use [GuildMember#permissionsIn()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=permissionsIn) to check the client's permissions in a certain channel

```js
const botMember = message.guild.me;
if (!botMember.permissionsIn(CHANNEL).has('permission')) {
   // Code
} else {
   // Error Handling 
}
```

As shown in other answers, you can also handle the promise rejection using `.catch()` or `catch () {}`

Ensure you're `await`ing any promise function when using `async/await + try/catch`

```js
// Example

try {
   await message.channel.send(...);
} catch (err) {
   // Handle err
}

message.channel.send(...)
   .then(msg => {})
   .catch(err => {
      // Handle err
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this in multiple ways

1. Wrap it in a try/catch statement

This would look something like:

```js
try{
    // Do this
} catch (error) {
    // Do that
}
```

2. You caould use a .catch() function

```js
role.doSomething().catch((error) => {
    // Do that
})
```

If you wanted to see if the error code was due to a missing permission you could do:

```js
const { Constants } = require("discord.js")

try{
    // Do this
} catch (error) {
    // Do that
    if(error.code === Constants.APIErrors.MISSING_PERMISSIONS){
    // Do this and that    
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried now this method, but it doesn't go to catch (i added console.log("test: " + error into catch and its not printing anything)

Comment: Can you send the code you added to see where the problem lies?

Comment: ok there is the url: https://pastebin.com/AqicZMZL (i cant paste it here, because it is long)

Comment: What command was giving you errors?

Comment: every single one when i don't have permission to send messages

Comment: Is it still spitting out an error? Im not too sure why the catch would not run the console.log()

Comment: yeah, it doesn't do anything in catch

Comment: Thanks for help, but i realized that embeds needs Embed Links perm and i resolved checking channel permission by other answer here.

Answer (score 0):

You could try exception handling, if you're just wanting the bot to proceed without crashing it.

I would recommend at least logging the error in console. For this example I'll use a try/catch block.

```
try{
    await doSomethingThatRequiresPermissions();
}catch(error){
    console.log("Error: "+error+" at doSomethingThatRequiresPermissions");
}
```

[NodeJS error handling documentation](https://nodejs.dev/learn/error-handling-in-nodejs)

[Discord.js specific permission handling](https://javascript.tutorialink.com/catching-an-permission-error-problem-discord-js/)

Edit: I don't have access to my server at the moment (as I'm at work) but I will test this later to find a more comprehensive answer.

Comment: I tried now this method, but it doesn't go to catch (i added console.log("test: " + error into catch and its not printing anything)

Comment: I apologize. I would personally do `console.log(error.message)`. Thank you for your patience, and let me know how it works.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't go to catch (i added to catch console.log("test: " + error.message) and nothing happens